# FontFamily not working in Android Device in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have added many font-family and style into my asset folder in React-Native project. It's working fine in simulator, emulator, and iOS device. But some font won't work and not display in Android device.

I have try with **react-native link** and check the **asset** folder in Android app directory, nothing missing.

> Anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

I might have a solution for this. I had the same problem, the fonts were visible in my emulator, the font files are located under 'android/src/main/assets/fonts' and yet it wasn't visible on my physical android device (Huawei Honor 8X).

I found out that the problem was with my physical device's Font settings. To fix this, on your phone, go to

*Settings -> Display -> Text Style -> Default*

**Settings screen : Go to Display**
[image: Settings screen : Go to Display]

**Display settings : Look for Text Style, Make sure it is set to default as seen in the pic**
[image: Display settings : Look for Text Style, Make sure it is set to default as seen in the pic]

**Select Default here : Now your custom app fonts should work**
[image: Select Default here : Now your custom app fonts should work]

Please Note that these settings might differ as per your device. I've mentioned the steps for my phone.

Always use the default Text Style to render custom fonts in your app.
Nowadays, phones like the OnePlus etc. have their own custom fonts and I think this is interfering with custom fonts defined in Applications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One user if my app was having the same issue on Huawei device. Changing the font to default solved their issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e) article worked for me. The name of the font file name is important to get it working on both platforms.

I had multiple font files with different weights (Circular Std Bold, Circular Std Medium etc..) for these to work on android I dynamically changed the font family style to this name to change the weight.

The font weight style on android didn't work for me.

Comment: Not help, changing and got complicated.
I really need to work on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with devices that have custom font style like huawei devices. I hope there be a solution for this to not force the user to change it's device font style because of our app.

Answer (score 0):

My font family changes when I connect to my android device but I finally figured out how to fix it. If font weight is set then it changes the font on my device to its default font. After I removed font weight my android devices default font isn't applied anymore.

Answer (score -1):

fontFamily its not work in inlinstyle you must change from

`<Text style={{fontFamily:'SantPro'}} />`

to
    Text style={styles.text}

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   text: {
        fontFamily:'SantPro',

    },
})
```