# Typeface not applied on Huawei EMUI

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-fonts, huawei-mobile-services, android-typeface

I'm applying a typeface like so:

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text).apply {
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/blackjack.otf")
}
```

It works in the emulator and on most Android devices, but it has no effect on Huawei devices with a system font selected.

One such device has the following specs:

```
EMUI 4.1
Model number EVA-L09
Android Version 6.0
```

How can I set the font on a device like this? and more importantly, how can I set the font with `Span`s? that also doesn't work on this device with an alternate system font selected.

Comment: refactor .otf to .ttf

Comment: Thanks, but using a ttf had no effect. Emulator works, Huawei doesn't. I also tried setting the Huawei's system font to default, but now it's just stuck on Roboto or similar.

Comment: Did you try textview.setTypeFace(typeface);

Comment: This is the equivalent Kotlin code.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: One explicit fix for Huawei phone is described here: [FontFamily not working in Huawei Device in React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53921674/593709)

Answer (score 0):

You can tried by clean . build and uninstall old APK to devices some device . keeps cache .

Comment: It's quite reproducible. I get the same result even with first install, and it works on the emulator.

Comment: Have you check with some other ttf or otf file may be there is some problem in your typeface file.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried an otf and a ttf that work on the emulator, but not on this device.

Comment: Huawei has it's own themes app that enables you to change the system font device-wide. So they're doing something to change the font, apparently even when it is set to "default".

Comment: I have a system font file Huawei Nova Regular located here `/system/fonts/Huawei-Nova-Regular.ttf` but when I apply it, text disappears from `TextView`. This is Huawei's _system font_.

Comment: I think in the end it was a bug on this exact version of the OS, and when the user updated the OS, the bug was fixed.